# Android using of switch option in pre ICS

Tags: android

I have a question in form which asks the user

> Will you attend event?

with the options of

> Yes/No

I am using Switch widget for android 4.0 and above,which is the best way for pre 4.0 versions.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be Multiple Options

1. [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)
2. 2 [RadioButton](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html&ei=fflsUbL4OeutiQel7IGQAw&usg=AFQjCNGgAbD-WvB0H3N65IZfwNJBnfNoxg&bvm=bv.45175338,d.aGc) as @Ascorbin suggested
3. A single [CheckBox](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html&ei=g_lsUZf2H8-iiAfwmoHADw&usg=AFQjCNHmQTsWzJlodW7qW9drxrFM_gQSGw&bvm=bv.45175338,d.aGc)

The best thing is dependant on your design

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 radio buttons, [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/) pretty much covers it.

Comment: You should include essential part of the answer here.